# Problems with this code?

Tags: android, calendar, syntax-error

I'm trying to use this code which is an example taken from here https://gist.github.com/2383248 , but it is coming up with a error on the public void onClick which is

Multiple markers at this line
- implements android.view.View.OnClickListener.onClick
- Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody, but when I add the brace it just throws another error after many tries and fails of different suggestions and ideas.

It may be a syntax error and bad coding from me (just started learning to program) but does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this or point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

```
 public class ICSCalendarActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button button1;

int year1;  
int month1;  
int day1;
int ShiftPattern;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openButton);     
    button1.setText("open");   
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

    year1 = extras.getInt("year1"); 
    day1 = extras.getInt("day1"); 
    month1 = extras.getInt("month1");

    ShiftPattern = extras.getInt("ShiftPattern");
}

public void onClick(View v){

private static void addToCalendar(Context ICSCalendarActivity, final String title, final long dtstart, final long dtend) {
    final ContentResolver cr = ICSCalendarActivity.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor ;
    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 )
        cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "displayname" }, null, null, null);
    else
        cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "displayname" }, null, null, null);
    if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
        final String[] calNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        final int[] calIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i < calNames.length; i++) {
            calIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
            calNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ICSCalendarActivity);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(calNames, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("calendar_id", calIds[which]);
                cv.put("title", title);
                cv.put("dtstart", dtstart );
                cv.put("hasAlarm", 1);
                cv.put("dtend", dtend);

                Uri newEvent ;
                if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 )
                    newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), cv);
                else
                    newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"), cv);

                if (newEvent != null) {
                    long id = Long.parseLong( newEvent.getLastPathSegment() );
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put( "event_id", id );
                    values.put( "method", 1 );
                    values.put( "minutes", 15 ); // 15 minutes
                    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 )
                        cr.insert( Uri.parse( "content://com.android.calendar/reminders" ), values );
                    else
                        cr.insert( Uri.parse( "content://calendar/reminders" ), values );

                }
                dialog.cancel();
            }

        });

        builder.create().show();
    }
    cursor.close();
}    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can't just declare a method inside another like this.

Comment: More specifically, you're trying to define the static method `addToCalendar` inside your `onClick` method.

Comment: thanks your answer triggered a redface, with "onClick method" ie method being the operative word. I was trying to do it all the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a **`static`** method definition `addToCalendar` inside the `onClick` function.

```
public class ICSCalendarActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button button1;

int year1;  
int month1;  
int day1;
int ShiftPattern;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openButton);     
    button1.setText("open");   
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

    year1 = extras.getInt("year1"); 
    day1 = extras.getInt("day1"); 
    month1 = extras.getInt("month1");

    ShiftPattern = extras.getInt("ShiftPattern");
}

public void onClick(View v){
      addToCalendar(mContext, mString, mlong,  mlong); // pass the parameters of the addToCalendar method here 
      }

private static void addToCalendar(Context ICSCalendarActivity, final String title, final long dtstart, final long dtend) {
    final ContentResolver cr = ICSCalendarActivity.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor ;
    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 )
        cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "displayname" }, null, null, null);
    else
        cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "displayname" }, null, null, null);
    if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
        final String[] calNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        final int[] calIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i < calNames.length; i++) {
            calIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
            calNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ICSCalendarActivity);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(calNames, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("calendar_id", calIds[which]);
                cv.put("title", title);
                cv.put("dtstart", dtstart );
                cv.put("hasAlarm", 1);
                cv.put("dtend", dtend);

                Uri newEvent ;
                if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 )
                    newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), cv);
                else
                    newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"), cv);

                if (newEvent != null) {
                    long id = Long.parseLong( newEvent.getLastPathSegment() );
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put( "event_id", id );
                    values.put( "method", 1 );
                    values.put( "minutes", 15 ); // 15 minutes
                    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 )
                        cr.insert( Uri.parse( "content://com.android.calendar/reminders" ), values );
                    else
                        cr.insert( Uri.parse( "content://calendar/reminders" ), values );

                }
                dialog.cancel();
            }

        });

        builder.create().show();
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you an obvious rookie mistake, but still once I have removed the onClick function it gives this error; The method addToCalendar(Context, String, long, long) from the type ICSCalendarActivity is never used locally.

Comment: Are you passing the values to the function while calling it inside onClick ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Im having trouble with passing the values, could you provide an example and explanation? any help to help me understand is gratefully received.

Comment: You are welcome! And well, to pass the values you need to do the same way you were doing it in your own code. I mean to say that even in yur code you had this function declaration and you were passing values to it, right ?

Comment: thanks I've got the code working but doesn't seem to insert the event into the calendar, So its working not crashing but not inserting the event, will have to mess with it some more and figure why. thanks

Comment: No problem. I suggest you post your calendar specific code in a new question. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a method inside another method. In your code you have defined**addToCalendar()** method inside the onClick() method. Instead define the method outside and call it from the onClick() method.

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
     addTocalender(context, string, longVal1,  longVal2);
}

private static void addToCalendar(Context ICSCalendarActivity,
        final String title, final long dtstart, final long dtend)
{
 ....
 ....
}
```